# How do I check if variable exists in a jsp page includes by another page

Tags: java, jsp

Usually my jsps contain the following at the start

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp"%>
<%! String language ="en"; %>    
<%@ include file="/layout/inc/pagestart.jsp" %>
```

and pagestart.jsp contains

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="<%=language%>">
```

which works fine.

But if the main jsp doesnt include the language variable defn then compilation fails with

```
An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /layout/inc/pagestart2.jsp
language cannot be resolved to a variable
1: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
2: <html lang="<%=language%>">
3: <%@ include file="/layout/inc/head.jsp"  %>
4: <%@ include file="/layout/inc/bodystart.jsp" %>
5: <%@ include file="/layout/inc/header.jsp" %>


    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

How do I modify pagestart.jsp so that it just defaults to ouputting

```
<html lang="en">
```

if the variable has not been setn

**Solution based on Alex Clems answer**
This still works if calling page doesn't set attribute

pagestart.jsp

```
<%! String language = "en"; %>
<% 
String lang = (String) request.getAttribute("language"); 
if(lang != null) {
    language = lang;
}
out.print("<html lang=\""+language+"\">");
%>
```

callingjsp.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp"%>
<% request.setAttribute("language", "de"); %>
<%@ include file="/layout/inc/pagestart.jsp" %>
```

Comment: Why not use your framework or a filter to provide the value if one doesn't exist already? I'm not convinced this kind of work belongs in (what I believe should be) a very dumb view layer.

Comment: I just need to get this working in a situation where I cannot redeploy the whole app again, I just copy over jsps as they are fixed so I need something that work with old and new code, please do you have a solution

Comment: I mean, it's a compilation error, not a runtime error. You could put something that defines `language` somewhere, but then you might get redeclaration errors. Put the value in page or request scope instead, e.g., *stop using scriptlets* and use JSTL.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hmm, my jsp skills are very rusty I cant remember how this jsp stuff now works is there not a one line code change I can make to fix this for now, and I can look at the whole architecture at a later date.

Comment: No, there isn't, IIRC--if there's a `language` scriptlet var already declared, declaring it again is an error. If there isn't one declared, you can't reference it. Why wouldn't you just put the header file everywhere? You've been coded into a corner--you can either fix it right, or fix it wrong like it's a decade ago.

Comment: I would fix if I understood your answer, but without some actual code Im afraid I dont.

Comment: "Put the header file in the files where it isn't already" seems pretty straight-forward; I'm not really sure how else to say it--sorry :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81338/discussion-between-paul-taylor-and-dave-newton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the variable exist and if it does then output what you need and if it doesn't output your default value.

In your first JSP change the way you set your `language`:

```
request.setAttribute("language", "en");
```

So that in your second JSP you can access `language` as:

```
String language = (String) request.getAttribute("language");
<% if(language != null) {
    out.print("<html lang=\"" + language + "\">");
} else {
    out.print("<html lang=\"en\">");
}
%>
```

Comment: Thanks Ive implemented your solution with just a few modifications shown above

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pageContext`:

calling.jsp:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("language", "en"); %>
<jsp:directive.include file="pagestart.jsp"/>
```

pagestart.jsp:

```
<html lang="${language}">
```

Or use `jsp:include`

calling.jsp:

```
<jsp:include page='pagestart.jsp'>
    <jsp:param name="language" value="en"/>
</jsp:include>
```

pagestart.jsp:

```
<html lang="${param.language}">
```

Comment: pageContext.attribute versus request.attribute - whats the advantage ?

Comment: Its basically a different scope see this question for more information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076979/is-this-are-same-or-different-pagecontext-scope-and-some-of-implicit-objects-thi

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK.. No, you can't check duplicate unless there is a compilation error at the run time.

In this scenario like including the pages, the best solution is to name the varible such that, it contains the file name prefixed (case sensitive) to it like below.

Example:  myvariable.jsp

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
    <%@ page errorPage="error.jsp"%>
    <%! String language ="en"; %>    
    <%@ include file="/layout/inc/pagestart.jsp" %>
```

pagestart.jsp contains

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html lang="<%=language%>">
```

rename the variable in myvariable.jsp

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
    <%@ page errorPage="error.jsp"%>
    <%! String myvariable_jsp_Language ="en"; %>    
    <%@ include file="/layout/inc/pagestart.jsp" %>
```

pagestart.jsp contains

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html lang="<%=myvariable_jsp_Language>">
```

Note: Due to low reputation, I can't add comments and had to contribute this as an answer. Don't downvote this, instead suggest corrections by comment on the same.